# I get an error 'String' cannot match values in my Switch statement using swift, why?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I am getting the following error when trying to use a `switch` statement on `currentState` which of type `MJMaterialSwitchState` in the delegate method `switchStateChanged` below.

```
  Error: xpression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'MJMaterialSwitchState'
```

I am using a custom [MJMaterialSwitch](https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJMaterialSwitch) UI which works perfectly. It toggles between an `on` and `off` state

Function:

```
func switchStateChanged(_ switcher: MJMaterialSwitch, currentState: MJMaterialSwitchState) {

        tapticGenerator.notificationOccurred(.success)

            switch currentState{

                case "on":
                    discoverable = true

                case "off":
                    discoverable = false

                default:
                    break
            }

}
```

This is the `MJMaterialSwitchState`:

```
public enum MJMaterialSwitchState {
    case on, off
}
```

Comment: what is `MJMaterialSwitchState`?

Comment: MJMaterialSwitchState is not a String (probably a enum) so you have to use those values in switch cases

Comment: A `switch` for a simple boolean check is overkill, this does the same: `discoverable =  currentState == .on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switch cases should be `MJMaterialSwitchState` instead of `String` values.

```
switch currentState {
    case .on:
        discoverable = true
    case .off:
        discoverable = false
}
```

Also, you do not need a `default` case if you cover all the cases in an `enum`.

Comment: Perfect! - exactly what I was looking for :)